# Formatting output using different elements of the same tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, formatting, tuples

I was looking for any advice on how to best format output from a tuple? It involves a large dataset that I have normalized as far as [key1: [value1, value2] from two dictionaries that contained key1:value1; key1:value2. Currently my output produces an output like this example: {1: [771, 'MALICE MIZER'],...  However, I am trying for this format: MALICE MIZER(1) 771. If anyone has advice, I'd appreciate it.

```
sorted_aid2numplay= sorted(aid2numplay.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True) 
#print(sorted_aid2numplay)

sorted_uid2numplay= sorted(uid2numplay.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True) 
#print(sorted_uid2numplay)

sorted_aid2name = sorted(aid2name.items(), key=itemgetter(0), reverse=False) 
#print(sorted_aid2name)

result = {}
for key in (aid2numplay.keys() | aid2name.keys()):
    #if key in aid2numplay: result.setdefault(key, []).append(aid2numplay[key])
    #if key in aid2name: result.setdefault(key, []).append(aid2name[key])
    if key in aid2numplay and aid2name:
        print((sorted_aid2name.itemgetter(0), key, sorted_uid2numplay.itemgetter(1))
        #print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a `for` loop and `format` method to print the results from your dictionary. see the example below

```
mydict = {1: [771, 'MALICE MIZER'], 43: [536, 'HARRY POTTER']}
for key,value in mydict.items():
    print '{v[1]}({k}) {v[0]}'.format(k=key,v=value)
```

results in

```
MALICE MIZER(1) 771
HARRY POTTER(43) 536
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect.